# javascript error: Cannot read property 'scrollIntoView' of undefined

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, instagram

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
import side


class InstaBot:
    def __init__(self, username, password):
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:/Users/ilias/PycharmProjects/Instabot/chromedriver.exe")
        self.driver.get("https://instagram.com")
        time.sleep(5)
        login_field = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/button[1]").click()
        time.sleep(2)
        login_field = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name=\"username\"]").send_keys(side.email)
        time.sleep(2)
        login_field = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name=\"password\"]").send_keys(side.password)
        time.sleep(2)
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/section/main/article/div[2]/div[1]/div/form/div/div[3]").click()
        time.sleep(5)
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/section/nav/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div/div[5]/span/img").click()
        time.sleep(2)
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/section/nav/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div/div[5]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/a[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div").click()
        time.sleep(2)

    def get_unfollowers(self):
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(@href,'/following')]") \
            .click()
        following = self._get_names()
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(@href,'/followers')]") \
            .click()
        followers = self._get_names()
        not_following_back = [user for user in following if user not in followers]
        print(not_following_back)

    def _get_names(self):
        time.sleep(2)
        self.driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollIntoView()')
        time.sleep(2)
        scroll_box = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[3]/div/div[2]")
        last_ht, ht = 0, 1
        while last_ht != ht:
            last_ht = ht
            time.sleep(1)
            ht = self.driver.execute_script("""
                arguments[0].scrollTo(0, arguments[0].scrollHeight); 
                return arguments[0].scrollHeight;
                """, scroll_box)
        links = scroll_box.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')
        names = [name.text for name in links if name.text != '']
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[3]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/button") \
            .click()
        return names


my_bot = InstaBot(side.email, side.password)
my_bot.get_unfollowers()
```

Hey, so I am making an Instagram bot to find out which accounts I follow without them following me.Everything went smoothly but when I get to self.driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollIntoView()') there seems to be an error I can't find a way around any ideas how to fix this?
error: selenium.common.exceptions.JavascriptException: Message: javascript error: Cannot read property 'scrollIntoView' of undefined

Comment: So arguments[0] does not contain an element that can be scrolled. Find out what it is and fix it

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) -> _"Introduce the problem before you post any code"_